# What can be a possible reason the PIC16LF1783 I2C Master mode code not working?

Tags: pic, i2c

I'm having an issue making my I2C code work as expected. I'm using PIC16LF1783 at master mode and trying to read slave reference ID from NFC Tag 4 click. While debugging the code I'm seeing that my code is stuck at line SSPBUF = addhigh. Can anybody please respond to what I'm doing wrong?
Purpose of the code: Read IC reference from the NFC Tag
Expected Output: 0x26
What I'm receiving: 0x57
Here is my code:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "config.h"
volatile char ret;
char ST25DV_IO_MemRead(const uint8_t DevAddr, char addhigh, char addlow, char Size)
{
 
 char data;
 uint8_t Addr = DevAddr >> 1; // 1010_1110 > 0101_0111

 if (Size == 1) { 
 SSPCON2bits.SEN = 1; //initiate start condition
 while(SEN); //wait for the start condition to complete
 PIR1bits.SSP1IF = 0; //clear SSP interrupt flag 
 
 SSPBUF = Addr; //Send the slave address
 while (!SSP1IF); //wait for ack, SSP1IF set every 9th clk cycle
 PIR1bits.SSP1IF = 0; //clear SSP interrupt flag
 if (SSPCON2bits.ACKSTAT)
 {
 SSPCON2bits.PEN = 1; //initiate stop condition
 while(PEN); //initiate stop condition
 return (0xFF); //Exit read (No ack) TODO return (0xFF);
 }
SSPBUF = addhigh; //Send the MSB
 while (!SSP1IF); //wait for ack, SSP1IF set every 9th clk cycle
 PIR1bits.SSP1IF = 0; //clear SSP interrupt flag
 if (SSPCON2bits.ACKSTAT)
 {
 SSPCON2bits.PEN = 1; //initiate stop condition
 while(PEN); //initiate stop condition
 return (0xFF); //Exit read (No ack)
 }
SSPBUF = addlow; //Send the LSB
 while (!SSP1IF); //wait for ack, SSP1IF set every 9th clk cycle
 PIR1bits.SSP1IF = 0; //clear SSP interrupt flag
 if (SSPCON2bits.ACKSTAT)
 {
 SSPCON2bits.PEN = 1; //initiate stop condition
 while(PEN); //initiate stop condition
 return (0xFF); //Exit read (No ack)
 }
SSPCON2bits.RSEN = 1; //receive the data byte from slave
 while(RSEN); //wait for the restart condition to complete
 PIR1bits.SSP1IF = 0; //clear SSP interrupt flag
SSPBUF = (Addr + 1); //Send the Slave address with R/W bit = 1
 while (!SSP1IF); //wait for ack, SSP1IF set every 9th clk cycle
 PIR1bits.SSP1IF = 0; //clear SSP interrupt flag
 if (SSPCON2bits.ACKSTAT)
 {
 SSPCON2bits.PEN = 1; //initiate stop condition
 while(PEN); //wait for the stop condition to complete
 return (0xFF); //Exit read (No ack)
 }
SSPCON2bits.RCEN = 1; //receive the data byte from slave
 while (!BF); //wait for the receive to complete
 data = SSPBUF; //store the data byte
SSPCON2bits.ACKDT = 1; //Prepare to send NACK
 SSPCON2bits.ACKEN = 1; //initiate NACK to tag
 while (ACKEN);
SSPCON2bits.PEN = 1; //initiate stop condition
 while(PEN); //wait for the stop condition to complete 
 return data;
}
 
}
 
 
void main(void) {
 
 
 OSCCONbits.IRCF = 12;
 
 SSPCON1 = 0b00101000; //SSP Module as Master
// SSPCON2 = 0; //Look at bit4-> ACKEN, bit3-> RCEN bit2 to 0
 SSPADD = 4; //Setting I2C Clock Speed --> 100kHz
// SSPSTAT = 0;
 TRISCbits.TRISC3 = 1; //Setting as input as given in datasheet 
 TRISCbits.TRISC4 = 1; //Setting as input as given in datasheet
 
 TRISCbits.TRISC5 = 1;
 char addhigh = 0x00;
 char addlow = 0x17;
 
 ret = ST25DV_IO_MemRead(0xAE, 0x00, 0x17, 1);
 
 return;
}
```

Following is the configuration file:

```
// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC // Oscillator Selection (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = OFF // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF // Data Memory Code Protection (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset disabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)
#pragma config IESO = ON // Internal/External Switchover (Internal/External Switchover mode is enabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)
// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = OFF // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config PLLEN = ON // PLL Enable (4x PLL enabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = LO // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
#pragma config LPBOR = OFF // Low Power Brown-Out Reset Enable Bit (Low power brown-out is disabled)
#pragma config LVP = ON // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (Low-voltage programming enabled)
// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.
#include <xc.h> // include processor files - each processor file is guarded.
```

My compiler is MPLAB XC8.

Thanks!

Comment: this leaps out ... `SSPCON2bits.SEN = 1;  while(SEN);` ... how is the value of SEN updated?

Comment: for me this :  `while(SEN)` won't compile. Use the complete Bit instead `SEN`. And please indent your code!.

Comment: To support Mike's comment: In C, any non-zero value is regarded as "true". Because I'm no expert in XC8, I assume that the bit definitions evaluate to some `int` compatible values. So your loops of the form `while(!some_bit)` might never execute, and the `while(some_bit)` might never quit.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the feedback. Just to be clear by saying complete bit do you guys mean using while (SSPCON2bits.SEN) instead of while (SEN)? I'll try replacing all these kinds of bits in my code and test it.